# How to check if a field has been populated with data using a javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Please note that i am a beginner in javascript. I've googled all the possible terms for my question but no luck. I wanted to know if there exists a javascript function that can be used to check if a field has been populated with data using another javascript function. No libraries please since i want to know the basics of javascript programming.

**Edit:** 
I just wanted to clarify that scenario that i am into.

I have 3 input fields. These fields have their value assigned automatically by another javascript function. What i wanted to do is when this fields have their respected values i wanted to create a new input field that will calculate the sum of the value of the 3 fields.

Comment: What do you mean with field? an input element on the page?

Answer (score 1):

As You are new Please try this whole code of HTML with Javascript code too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function copyText()
{
var TextValue = document.getElementById("field1").value
if(TextValue !=''){
alert(TextValue);
}
alert();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello World!"><br>

<button onclick="copyText()">Copy Text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

lets say this is your **html** field (text input for instance):

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
```

in order to get it's value with **javascript**, use `document.getElementById('txtName').value` - for example:

```
function alert_value() {
    var value = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
    alert(value);
}
```

hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

if this text field is added dynamically, i'd suggest including jQuery and set the following script:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('keyup', '#txtName', function(){ alert($(this).val()) });
});
```

Comment: please note that this field is generated dynamically. What i wanted originally is if this input field has been dynamically created, i want to attach a trigger (like onchange) that will check if this field has been filled with a value using javascript.

Comment: include jQuery and use: `$(document).on('keyup', '#txtName', function(){ alert($(this).val()) });`

Answer (score 0):

```
//HTML line:


<input type="text" id="txtAddress" />

        //JS code:


function setValue() {
        //first we set value in text field:
            document.getElementById('txtAddress').value = 'new value';
            TestFunction();
        }



        function TestFunction() {
        //second we will get value from this filed and check wether it contains data or not:
            var address = document.getElementById('txtAddress').value;
            if (address != "") {
                alert("Yes, field contains address");
            }
            else {
                alert("Empty field, there is no address");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please note that this field is dynamically created and the value assigned to it is dynamically assigned by a javascript function.

Comment: First you need to assign some value to this field. e.g. $("#txtAddress").val("hi it's my address"); Then you will check whether  the field contains data or not from my above function. Thanks.

Comment: please see edit to post and do let me know if that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
//Html Code
<input type="text" value="sdsd" onChange="checkValue(this.value)">


//Java Script Code
function checkValue(value){
    if((value).trim()!==""){
       alert('return true');   
    }
    else{
        alert('return false');   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve.

If you want to check if the input to the field was made with Javascript : there's no way to make that UNLESS your Javascript input function stores such information in some place (for example, add specific class to the modified object). Then you can proceed with following:

If you want to check if there's any value in the field then you can use `onchange` (triggers on change, you can pass the object to the function and get every property attached to it - value, class etc.).

example:

```
function changeValue( object )
{
    object.value = "new value";
    object.classList.add("modified");
}

function isChanged( object )
{
    if( object.classList.contains("modified") )
        alert("I'm modified by JS!");
}

<input type="text" id="first" onchange="isChanged(this)">
```

It has been some time since I was writing JS, but this should work.

Edit: now I remember onchange triggers only, if element is edited by user, thus rendering `onchange` detection worthless. Well, you could use set interval with the following function:

```
function getModified() {
    // somehow process with
    // document.getElementsByClassName("modified"); 
} 
setInterval( getModified(), 3000 ); // get JS modified elements every 3s
```